# Change an image on click onto another image, but use the srcset functionality (jquery optional)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, srcset

I want to change an image onclick on another image, but don't only want to change a fixed image but use the advantages of srcset, so the browser picks the right image for the current main image size (responsive layout).

This is what I am using right now, vanilla:

```html
<div id="item-detail-img-main">
  <img src="/_img/items/400/img.jpg" srcset="/_img/items/400/img.jpg 400w, /_img/items/600/img.jpg 600w" alt="" width="100%" id="item-detail-img-main-img">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function chimg (img) {
  window.document.images["item-detail-img-main-img"].src = img;
}
</script>
<ul id="item-detail-img-thumbs">
  <li><img src="/_img/items/200/img.jpg" onclick="chimg('/_img/items/400/img.jpg')"></li>
  <li><img src="/_img/items/200/img2.jpg" onclick="chimg('/_img/items/400/img2.jpg')"></li>
</ul>
```

I'm open to jquery here.

Anyone know how to handle this?

Comment: you want to set an image by the width of the screen? or another element? how do you want to determine the size? please explain better.

Comment: By the available space in item-detail-img-main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can probably set the srcset attribute, at least by using the `setAttribute()` method. You could also just replace the whole image tag:

```
function(img,img2,img3){
    document.getElementById('item-detail-img-main').innerHTML='<img src="'+img+'" srcset="'+img2+' 400w, '+img3+' 600w" alt="" width="100%" id="item-detail-img-main-img">';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery option looks something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/axcnotx7/

```
<div>
  <img id="main" width="100%" id="item-detail-img-main-img">
</div>
<ul id="thumbs">
  <li><img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fi3ur/fruitsalad/256/banana-icon.png"></li>
  <li><img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/bingxueling/fruit-vegetables/256/apple-red-icon.png"></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var main = $('img#main');
    $('#thumbs img').click(function(e) {
        var imageSrc = e.currentTarget.src;
        // You need to determine your own srcset paths here
        var srcSet = imageSrc + ' 400w, ' + imageSrc + ' 600w';
        main.attr('src', imageSrc);
        main.attr('srcset', srcSet);
    });
</script>
```